# Mesh shows up correctly in object mode but not in render view

Tags: mesh, topology, retopology

I have a mesh that shows up correctly in object mode but not in render view. Here are some pictures: [image]

This is in rendered mode and as you can see there is weird indentations.

This is the image in object mode (what I want it to look like):
[image]

I was thinking it could be the mesh has points extruded out a bit more than others but I checked and they were all level. So I was wondering what could be wrong. This is a picture of the mesh:

[image]

I notice that not all faces are quadrilaterals could that be the reason? If not how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: It is possible that some of the normals are flipped. In edit mode press alt N to recalculate normals outside.

Comment: I tried that sadly it didn't work

Comment: Does object have any modifiers set to different values for rendering and preview? Or turned off for viewport but being on for render? Is there any object overlapping the shown one?

Comment: It is hard to help when you cut the images so tight. Are there other objects or collections that are hidden in the outliner?

Comment: The white dots make me think this is harware related, do you have an AMD graphics card ?